# Why is my function in Google Sheet not working?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have a spreadsheet with registrations for a Summer Camp. I want to filter the registrations based on location, in a new spreadsheet.

**I have used the following code:**
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BDv-P3Bx8kHLSEUILmFBMmSB502-LUkQ8oiw8BYaPyo/","Inschrijvingen!A2:W2800"),"SELECT * WHERE Col1 contains 'Amersfoort - Groep 1-2'")

It keeps on saying: error.

The second image is the main file with all registrations.

[image: Google sheet code]

[image: All registrations]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event your spreadsheet locale uses comma `,` instead of period `.` as decimal mark, you will have to use semicolons `;` as formula argument separators, like this:

```
=query( 
  importrange("1BDv-P3Bx8kHLSEUILmFBMmSB502-LUkQ8oiw8BYaPyo"; "Inschrijvingen!A1:W"); 
  "where Col1 contains 'Amersfoort - Groep 1-2' "; 
  1
)
```

You can choose the spreadsheet locale at **File > Settings > Locale**.